# Behavior of hook_update_N hooks

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I noticed that when I have two updates for my custom module, and I select the first update, Drupal will run also the second update, without to manually select the second. Is this normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code in update.php it appears that this is infact that case. Selecting a module update will run that update and all updates after it.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/update.php/6/source

Comment: Yes, it always runs the one you've selected (which is by default the next higher one than the value in {system}.schema_version.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal will always run all the updates after the one already run for the specific module, and recorded in the system table.

Normally you don't need to select which update Drupal must run, but even if you do it, Drupal will always run the selected update and any consecutive ones.